# Recover deleted Notes on iOS

Tags: iphone

I deleted a note accidentally.  I found it in my deleted notes.  It will stay there for 30 days and then delete forever it says.  How do I get it saved back into Notes from Deleted Notes?

Answer (score 1):

Swipe it left.

You get 2 options, Move & Delete.

Move allows to to move it back to where it came from, or anywhere else.
[Delete is permanent from that folder, so be careful]